# getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); throws NullPointerException on new activity creation (Google - Basic Tutorial)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar

I am following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) and getting a NullPointerException at the onCreate method of the DisplayMessageActivity at this block of code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
// Show the Up button in the action bar.
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Exception here
}
```

I am running the app at an emulator following the NexusOne AVD template.
When I click the send button with some text typed in I get the exception.

Here is the log:

```
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage.myfirstapp/com.mypackage.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at com.mypackage.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity.onCreate(DisplayMessageActivity.java:40)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-03 23:02:07.586: E/AndroidRuntime(7095):     ... 11 more
```

By commenting this block the app runs successfuly.

Why is a NullPointerException thrown?

Comment: This means that action bar does not exist. See if your theme mentioned in manifest file supports action  bar.

Answer (score 31):

You are probably using a Theme that doesn't support `ActionBar`. Hence `getActionBar()` method throws `NullPointerException`.

Trying using this theme:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

Comment: You probably have a `ThemeName.NoActionBar` in your AndroidManifest.xml... Just remove the `.NoActionBar` part and you're good to go! Check `res/styles.xml` for available styles... (Android Studio here, in other editors you have to code the style yourself)

Answer (score 31):

Try changing `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()` or `((ActionBarActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar()`.

Comment: Any explanation on _why_ this solves the problem would improve your answer.

Comment: I also had this problem recently, and solved it by doing this.

Comment: Change import android.app.ActionBar; to import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem.

In the activity of the manifest i had declared

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar
```

which caused the error. After removing this line, my actionbar worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

It shouldn't be necessary but there are some behavior inconsistencies between API versions even after API level 14.

Behavior:

Back "<" image is displayed but it doesn't work when pressed. 
As a good practice I use to implement the switch case in order to handle back event.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error when I was trying out the navigation drawer sample app available at the android developer site. It turns out the `MainActivity` did not extend the `ActionBarActivity` and thus `getActionBar()` returns null causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers worked for me, really. I just commented out that whole `if` and it worked. From the method name ([and documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean))), you don't need that functionality anyway (unless you want it), so no harm done.

Relevant documentation excerpt:

> Set whether home should be displayed as an "up" affordance. Set this
>   to true if selecting "home" returns up by a single level in your UI
>   rather than back to the top level or front page.
>
> To set several display options at once, see the setDisplayOptions
>   methods.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `showHomeAsUp`    true to show the user that selecting home will
>   return one level up rather than to the top level of the app.

Answer (score 0):

**You must have set some theme with your Activity which is not compatible with the Action bar.**

So just **check the theme** you are using with in your **manifest file and remove it**

or if you have defined **custom theme** go to your **res->values->style.xml**
and make **WindowActionBar to true.**