# Android How Do I get TTS to read From a Pre-Populated TextView

Tags: android

Hi I really need some help with getting Android TTS to read from a pre-populated textview when the user clicks a button

my layout file currently consists of 1x button 1x textview and 1x imageView

any references or Ideas will be of great help.

here's my code

```
public class Bulbasaur extends Activity{
ListView l;
ImageView img;
TextView tv1;
Button btn1;
MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bulbasaur);
    img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.national001);
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

    tv1.setText("Dex Entry 001:\n" +
                "Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight.\n" +
                "There is a seed on its back.\n" +
                "By soaking up the sun's rays, \n" +
                "the seed grows progressively larger.");
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.cryBtn);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bulbasaur);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // API 5+ solution
            onBackPressed();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
}
```

ok thanks for the help :)
but now it is crashing with these errors

```
Process: net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex, PID: 1775
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex/net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex.Bulbasaur}: java.lang.ClassCastException: net.metaruptdonations.MetaDex.Bulbasaur cannot be cast to android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$OnInitListener
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    public void onClick(View v) {
         String speak_text = tv1.getText();
         tts.speak(speak_text , TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
   });
```

Comment: thanks, but now TextToSpeech(this,this) is showing an error

Comment: you need to add a listener for texttospeech

Comment: @Vynllazuril implement this android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener

Comment: the implementation removes the error but it still crashes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602953/getactionbar-setdisplayhomeasupenabledtrue-throws-nullpointerexception-on-n?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: ok I fixed to oncreate crash now trying to fix the onclick crash

Comment: fixed it, forgot to declare that dexterBtn as a button stupid mistake on my behalf